# What does the word 「はわして」mean?

Tags: words, manga

Here is the sentence including the word.

いまにおめをぶちのめして　みみずみたいに地を**はわして**やるぜっ。

I found that 「這う」 would be closest meaning of it but when conjugate to て-form it is 這って which is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your guess about 這う is correct, except it causative form which means "to make crawl". Normally that is 這わせて, however it seems that in some dialects せ can change to し, so you end up with はわして.

[Here](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/4489754.html) is one thread which discuses saying 見して instead of　見せて.

The overall tone of this line is pretty harsh, and sounds like it was said by a pretty scary guy. Here is my rough translation:

> I'm going to beat you to a pulp and then make you crawl on the ground like an
>   earthworm!

Comment: In Tokyo dialect we often use す as a variant of せる. Thus 書かす (< 書かせる), 触らす (< 触らせる) and 這わす (< 這わせる). But 見して is a pure analogy because there's no verb 見す (見せる is one indivisible word).